# javax.mail.AuthenticationException - Google cloud app Engine - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently working on a spring boot application when i'm required to send mail at specific moment, so i used the **javax.mail** api to do so, the program works fine on local machine but when i deploy the application in google cloud app engine, i keep getting the following error:

**javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException**

i tried to follow google cloud documentation instructions when it comes to mailing requirement but i keep getting the same error.

following my code.*

```
                public boolean sendMail(String indicator, String destination, String hotelName, String username, String password) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(env.getProperty(IConstants.mailAddress),
                            env.getProperty(IConstants.mailPass));
                }
            });

            String indic = null;
            if(indicator.equals("R")){
                indic = "RECEPTIONIST";
            }

            if(indicator.equals("M")){
                indic = "ROOMMAID";
            }

            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(env.getProperty(IConstants.mailAddress)));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(destination));
                message.setSubject(indic + "Hotel " + hotelName + " - Credentials");
                message.setText("Hello " + hotelName
                        + " Employee, Down Below Your Credentials for a secure access to your workspace " + ".\n USERNAME: "
                        + username + " PASSWORD: " + password + ".\n" + "Greetings.");
                Transport.send(message);
                return true;
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

The sender mail is on the authorized mail senders list, everything is correctly configured, the app responds to all the requests, but keeps failing at sending mail step.

I enabled the less security application authentication option on the sender gmail account but it keep rejecting the authentication attempts.

Thanks.

Comment: It could be that the environment variables are not correctly set, since it's working locally but not when deployed. Try printing  `env.getProperty(IConstants.mailAddress)` and `env.getProperty(IConstants.mailPass)`. Also try to put the values directly in the arguments like this `PasswordAuthentication("myAddress@mail.com","myPassword")`

Comment: You cannot use an external SMTP provider to send mail in GAE. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234656/unable-to-send-email-from-google-app-engine). you can use the [App Engine Mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/mail/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I kept trying multiple configurations to make it work but it didn't, so i switched to another option, i implemented the **sendGrid** solution, **google cloud** listed it as a possible alternative approach, it was so simple, so secure and it worked from first attempt.

[SendGrid implementation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid)

Thanks for ur suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Were you using standard env or flexible env. In our case we used flexible env with google smtp mailing. 
It is working fine for us. And I suspect the issue in your case is with the third party access check of google mail account. 
Try the same smtp after enabling this option so that your application will be able to access the gmail smtp.

> Turn on access from the settings shown in screenshot for the account which is being used from smtp

[image]

Although the sendgrid is a nice mailing service. But we prefered google smtp only.